# Similar looking screenshots after clicking

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to take screenshot of [this page](http://www.optus.com.au/shop/broadband/mobile-broadband/data-sim-card) using Selenium. But as Chrome and Firefox does not allow full page screenshot, I am using PhantomJS.

There are 2 sets of durations: `12 Month` and `Month-to-Month`. Hence I am trying to click each tab and take a screenshot.

The code to get the content of the page is:

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.set_window_size(1366, 728)
browser.get("http://www.optus.com.au/shop/broadband/mobile-broadband/data-sim-card")
delay = 30 # seconds
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, delay)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.price")))
    print("\nPage is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

To get the css classnames of the durations:

```
durations = soup.body.find("ul", attrs={'class': 'filter-options grouped'})
duration_filtrs = {}
for content in durations.contents:
    duration = content.text  # Storage of the model 64GB, 256GB, 512GB
    css_clss = list(filter(lambda x: x not in ['', 'active'], content.attrs['class']))
    filtr_nm = '.' + '.'.join(css_clss)
    duration_filtrs[duration] = filtr_nm

print(duration_filtrs) 
# {'12 Months': '.filter-option.contract_length_12', 'Month to Month':'.filter-option.contract_length_1'}
```

To take the screenshot for each duration tab,

```
for duration, css_cls in duration_filtrs.items():
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css_cls).click()
    browser.save_screenshot(duration+'.png')
```

With the above code, even with slightly different file sizes, I get the similar looking screenshots.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean to say that tabs dont appear to have been switched?

Comment: The tabs  switch when I used Chrome (instead of PhantomJS) and the screenshots (even though they are not full page) look correct to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to fix that issue in PhantomJS. I recommend a workaround with Chrome headless as follow. You just need to specify the window size.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=2160,3840") # you can adjust the size as you want
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
...
...
for duration, css_cls in duration_filtrs.items():
    button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,css_cls)))
    browser.save_screenshot('before-'+duration+'.png')
    print(button.text)
    button.click()
    time.sleep(8)
    browser.save_screenshot(duration+'.png')
```

Comment: Thanks Buaban, for your script. +1 for this. I never new how to run `Chrome headless` browser. Following your guideline I got success. Wished to know one thing though. Can `selenium headless browser` manage to click successfully, when in need, unlike `PhantomJS`?

Comment: @SIM Of course. Headless mode works the same as GUI mode.

Comment: Thankssssssss a lot for your sharp reply.

Comment: Thankss. I really want to capture the screenshots of the price section. Can you please tell me how to do it ?

Comment: These worked for me. Thankss
`options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument("window-size=2160x3840") # you can adjust the size as you want
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)`

Comment: Another question: in the month to month section, there are 5 prices but at a time only 3 can be seen, hence in the screenshots we can see 3. Do you know how to get the screenshots of all 5 prices in the same screenshot?